# How to select correct path to click item?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I tried to create a loop to click all links on a website https://www.hatvp.fr/le-repertoire/liste-des-entites-enregistrees/ one after another.

I found this part in the html code that could solve my problem: `a.orga-card-row:nth-child(i)` it's from the CSS selector, and increases with every item so `(1)`,`(2)` etc., so it should be easy to create a `for i in range` or `while` loop. An earlier version with the XPATH ran smoothly, but I have no clue how to create a loop with it, so this part would be an easier solution. Another problem is the variable in the call: I solved this with a `str(i)`, but since the first part of the code doesn't work, I don't know if that's sufficient.

```py
i=1

def wait_for_element_to_be_clickable(element):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, element)))

element = "a.orga-card-row:nth-child("+str(i)+")"
wait_for_element_to_be_clickable(element)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(element).click()
```

Tried everything I could do.

Comment: I think there are more than 3000 links on the web page, are you saying you want to click each one of them in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to do something like this without using indices. You get a list of links to click and just loop through that list, e.g.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
for link in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.orga-card-row"))):
    link.click()
    # switch to newly opened tab, do something, and close tab
```

NOTE: Normally I would wait for clickable if I'm going to click something but in this case, there is no wait for all elements to be clickable... it's only a single element so I needed to switch to `EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located`.

NOTE 2: If you run this code as is, it will quickly open a new tab for each link and run until it runs out of memory and something crashes. You'll want to make sure that you process each opened tab and close the tab before returning to the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clicking each link, alternative way to get the `href` value from the link in list and then iterate.

```
alllinks=[link.get_attribute("href") for link in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.orga-card-row")))]
for url in alllinks:
  driver.get(url)
  #Do something
  time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure I follow your requirement, giving you an idea based on my understanding of what you are after.

Check the below code. Below code will capture all the links first, then in a loop, just clicks on each link. As there are over 3000 links on the page, I am just clicking on the first 3 links, you can change it as per your need.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.hatvp.fr/le-repertoire/liste-des-entites-enregistrees/')

time.sleep(5)
# below line of code will capture all the links into a List
all_Links = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "orga-card-row")

# below for loop will iterate through the first 3 links and click on it, change the number :3 as per your need
for link in all_Links[:3]:
    link.click()

time.sleep(20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script for that using https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase for the extra useful methods needed for this, such as `sb.switch_to_newest_tab()` (so that you can do something on the new tab), and `sb.switch_to_default_tab()` (so that you can get back to the original tab easily).

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB() as sb:
    sb.open("https://www.hatvp.fr/le-repertoire/liste-des-entites-enregistrees/")
    sb.wait_for_element("#annuaire-ri div.annuaire-resultat a", timeout=15)

    limit = 5  # You probably don't want all 3252 rows.
    elements = sb.find_elements("a.orga-card-row", limit=limit)
    for element in elements:
        element.click()
        sb.switch_to_newest_tab()
        print("Page title: %s" % sb.get_title())
        sb.driver.close()  # Close current tab
        sb.switch_to_default_tab()
```

That prints the page titles of the new tabs. Output:

```
Page title: Fiche "pg Consultant"
Page title: Fiche #jesuislÀ
Page title: Fiche 1108 Rp
Page title: Fiche 1884-1901
Page title: Fiche 1979
```